# Newton's Law of Cooling and Taylor series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This isn't an exact problem, but I'm hoping for an explanation of an experiment I performed a while back.

I set up a temperature probe to measure the temperature of an object, and after results were given, I think I remember thinking that it didn't seem like an exponential function, but maybe a bad taylor series approximation for an exponential function. I can't remember...

Could anyone elaborate more on this?

Comment: The Newton Law of Cooling gives a poor approximation to actual cooling. Its main use is for calculus exercises.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Then what could better approximate its actual cooling?

Comment: Newton's law of cooling actually works quite well in certain circumstances.  In a lab course in engineering science I took while an undergrad at Caltech, we were given a steel ball with a thermal sensor at its center; after letting the ball sit for awhile to equilibrate to room temperature, we lowered it quickly into a dewar of liquid $N_2$; the exponential decay of temperature with time was quite apparent when we analyzed our data.  Of course, those were probably ideal conditions--a symmetrical object of uniform material, and a rather large temperature difference to begin with.  More . . .

Comment: There is some discussion of convective cooling [here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convective_heat_transfer) That is the only kin of cooling to which the Newton Law (in part) theoretically applies.

Comment: Continued:  Also, steel has a pretty high conductance for heat, I'll betcha . . . another thing I learned from that experiment was just how much fun a Caltech frosh can have with *all* that liquid nitrogen to play with after the lab was done . . . my girlfriend just *loved* the frozen roses . . . . ;-)

Comment: @AndréNicolas:  All I know is what I measured and the graphs we got . . . but hey, you may be right in general; on this cold December evening, I'm way more interested in ***thermo-*** than ***cryo-*** dynamics!  And a Warm and Cheery New Year's Eve to You, Good Sir!

Comment: The experiment you described is quite different from the coffee (or dead body) cooling of calculus problems. And a Happy New Year. Coolish here too, but better than the usual endless rain.

Comment: @AndréNicolas:  Yes, I agree; the experiment was no doubt designed to work as it did!

Answer (score 0):

I believe from your question that you do know that [Newton's Law of Cooling](http://www.ugrad.math.ubc.ca/coursedoc/math100/notes/diffeqs/cool.html) is solved by an exponential function, although you do not explicitly say so.

It is rare for a real-life measurement of anything to completely agree with the theory. Some theories are approximations, and most situations are impossible to limit to the variables you are modeling. In your case, the temperature change can be affected by stray air currents in the room. Your temperature probe is also not exact and is unlikely to give you the exactly correct reading.

In other words, it is normal for your actual data to be close to but not exactly the same as the prediction.

Comment: any way you could relate this to Taylor series? And yes the solution was an  exponential function